# Mudar do modo de inserção para o modo de cursor de digitação?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Quando abro um novo arquivo no PyCharm o cursor fica como se eu tivesse clicado na tecla Insert, alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Provavelmente, no momento da instalação do `PyCharm` você instalou a extensão para trabalhar com linguagem  `R`. Aconselho desinstalar o PyCharm, reinstala-lo, tomando cuidado de não instalar a extensão da linguagem `R`.

Comment: Foi exatamente isso, pena que demorou 1 dia inteiro pra entender o que aconteceu

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

No seu teclado numérico, aperte a tecla **0 (zero) **, isto irá retirar o modo insert ( Vim Emmulator).

Fonte: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207026025-Change-from-insert-to-type-over-cursor-mode-

Comment: Tentei já isso, mas não deu. Tem algo a ver com KeyMap mas não estou conseguindo resolver

Answer (score 1):

> Provavelmente, no momento da instalação do PyCharm você instalou a extensão para trabalhar com linguagem R. Aconselho desinstalar o PyCharm, reinstala-lo, tomando cuidado de não instalar a extensão da linguagem R. – Solkarped 18/09/20 às 19:48

Bastar ir na opção: Tools >> e **desmarcar** a opção 'Vim Emulator'.